# Raspberry Pi ffmpeg video4linux2, v4l2 mmap no such device

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, mmap, live-streaming, video4linux

On my Raspberry pi I've installed ffmpeg. At the begin I type

```
uv4l --driver raspicam --auto-video_nr --width 640 --height 480 --encoding jpeg
```

to run driver. Then I check if devoce0 is registered:

```
ls -la /dev/video*
```

and it returns video0 so it is registered. Then I type command to run server:

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -r 5 -s 640x480 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost/webcam.ffm
```

and the camera lights up for a while and then turns off and I get error like bellow:

```
[video4linux2, v4l2] mmap: No such device /dev/video0: No such device
```

What I should do to resolve it? It looks like internal error one of these libraries.

This command works:

```
uv4l --driver raspicam --auto-video_nr --encoding h264 --width 640 --height 480 --enable-server on
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`? If that helps, add `bcm2835-v4l2` into `/etc/modules` and reboot.

Comment: It works, thank you, I added bcm2835-v4l2 to /etc/modules and now it works. Sudo modprobe .. doesn't work

Comment: Excellent - I am glad it works. I have added it as a complete answer for all to find easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following line at the bottom of the file `/etc/modules` and rebooting your Raspberry Pi.

```
bcm2835-v4l2
```

Mine now looks like this *in toto*:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

bcm2835-v4l2
```

This ensures that the **Broadcom Video For Linux 2** (v4l2) driver is loaded at all subsequent reboots.